# Null values in CSV Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

I have this scenario which I am reading a CSV file for Example values, and load them into my input JSON:

```
Scenario Outline:
   * def inputJson = karate.read('../karate/data/sample.json')
   * print "Input JSON is: " + karate.pretty(inputJson)

   Examples:
   |read('classpath:karate/data/testData.csv')|
```

In my sample.json:

```
{
  "testField" : "#(testField)"
}
```

And in my testData.csv:

```
testField,a,b,c,...
null,,,...
```

When I print out inputJson, the value `null` of `testField` is read as a string `"null"`.

I also tried replacing the value as empty, as well as using `testField!` in my CSV header, but none of them loads the null value properly as `null`.

Any advice to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just use a transform, you can check for value == 'null' and set to `null`